# Ideas to stop water from spray head from going out of curbless shower

Tags: shower, overflow

We’re close to finish our first big project, curbless shower, but now running into a potential big problem with water shooting out too far from spray head and spill to the opposite wall where there will be no drain (arrow direction).

What I’m thinking of doing now is to add a shower door perpendicular with middle of the window where the design slope starts, but very unsure how esthetic it would look where the window will now be divided in half.

Looking for suggestions or any alternatives that would save us from killing our budget and retaining the shower we dream about :([image]

Comment: This needed to be addressed in the planning stage.  Sloping the floor toward the drain is a basic design item.

Comment: You filed the class, there has to be a slope towards the drain

Comment: If the problem is just over spray(?) I would try a simple shower curtain first and make sure it is not a drainage problem, before adding more expensive shower doors.

Comment: Was this installed by a contractor? If it's not sloped properly it's on them and they should redo it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the shower? Only 1 shower head and 1 wand. So shower for one.   Why does shower need to be more than 4'x4'. Personally I like enclosed shower to keep heat in. Need more details.

Comment: @justinj OTOH one benefit of a walk-in shower for me is that the whole bathroom warms up so it's not suddenly colder when you step out of the shower.

Comment: @JD74 OP says there is a particular place where the sloping begins.  A contractor might have reasonably assumed OP would install some glass there. A contractor might have reasonably assumed (s)he's not creating a community shower house. :)   Unless OP said "we are building a wet room, wall-to-wall" and then I think the drain would be in the middle, for starters.

Comment: What is the window frame made of?

Comment: This needs an actual question. If you're asking about the "aesthetic" of having a wall in the middle of a window, then I'd agree that's a bad idea, however, that's a design question that's off topic here. If you're asking if you should have sloped the entire floor toward the drain, then ask that. If you're asking for "any" ideas, then this is far too broad.

Comment: That said, when I was in Israel, our bathroom was about 12x12' with no shower curb, curtain or anything else to contain water. After a shower, the floor was almost dry by the time I was dry. Of course, that's a desert climate so YMMV.

Comment: @FreeMan I think that in Israel it's standard, almost universal, to do things that would benefit OP but that OP did not do, particularly: the bathroom is designed from the get-go as a wet room 1) the *entire* subfloor and subwalls are all made of poured concrete, 2) there is a central floor drain, 3) the window frames are aluminum not wood, 4) no high-power switches or outlets *anywhere* on the walls (switches outside, shaver outlet inside).  In the USA most of these things are only in VERY high end bathrooms and they do not seem to be in OP's.

Comment: Those are details I honestly don't recall @jay613, it was, ummm... a few moons ago... Well, the entire building was made of poured concrete. I'm pretty certain that there wasn't any finish beyond possibly a coat of paint on the inside.

Answer (score 2):

So long as the drain is fast enough to keep up, I wouldn't worry about it. [That may depend on territory - my folks live in Tenerife where the drains are smaller than the UK & theirs doesn't keep up, meaning any shower has a time limit:\

I've had a similar setup for 25 years & overspray has never been a concern. If you're worried about preserving the aesthetic, get a poolside squeegy for the closet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a rainfall shower head so that won't be a problem if the floor is sloped near the shower, because the water goes straight down.

The only issue would be from the handheld shower on the hose. The range on one of those with fast flow is such that you could soak the whole room without a shower screen. That's not necessarily a problem if you use it sensibly. A shower head chosen to not produce a fast stream would help, such as an aerating head or even just one with more, bigger, holes. An in-line flow reducer could be added later if there's a problem, but a suitably chosen head still allows lots of water, just not a blast.

That should get things down a manageable label of splashing if the users are reasonably sensible.

But if you do add a screen so late in the project, the place to do it is against the window frame close to the shower. This will look tidiest and you seem to have plenty of space (by the look of things, slightly more than my walk-in shower, that's open to the side only).

Answer (score 1):

Need first to double check the floor slope. If that's wrong, the only solution is to re-do the floor, with a slope towards the drain.

If the water is from the head itself, that could be changed, or the spray pattern altered, or the tap not opened so far as to create too much water flow.

If the problem is water from your body, then a shower curtain, which only gets closed when showering, would solve it. But it would need to go level with the beginning of the slope, so water hitting it, and dropping to the floor, would drain away properly.